# PHP Retrieve Database Value Error

Tags: php, database

So i have this so far..

```
if(isset($_POST['Decrypt']))
{
$dbinary = strtoupper($_POST['user2']);
$sqlvalue = "SELECT `value` FROM `license` WHERE `binary` = '$dbinary'";
$dvalue = mysql_query($sqlvalue) or die(mysql_error());
$dvalue = mysql_fetch_array($dvalue);
$dvalue['value'];
}
```

I have a field where the user enters a binary code which was encrypted. (The encrypt part works). This is supposed to retrieve the value from the database. When ever i do it, instead of the value showing up, it says "Array".

Please help me out.

Comment: how you tried to print it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you can't just `echo` an array. You need to use functions like [var_dump();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php);

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have more than one row in your table matching criteria. Try using `while` loop to retrieve data.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dvalue)){
    //$row['value'];
}
```